# How to change SQL query to a parameterized query

Tags: sql, node.js, prepared-statement

```
let query =

select * from (select acf.ID "call_flow_ID", acf.Name "CALL_FLOW_NAME", acf.SLO "SERVICE_OBJECTIVE", acf.LOG_FILTER "LOG_FILTER", acf.Max_jump,
(SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) FROM ACR_SUBROUTINE acs RIGHT JOIN ACR_CALL_FLOW_SUB ON SUB_ID=acs.ID WHERE FLOW_ID=acf.ID AND TYPE IN ('ANC') GROUP BY TYPE) "ANNOUNCEMENT_TREATMENT",
(SELECT NAME FROM ACR_USER_DOMAIN aud WHERE aud.DOMAIN_ID=acf.DOMAIN_ID) "DOMAIN_NAME",
(SELECT DOMAIN_ID FROM ACR_USER_DOMAIN aud WHERE aud.DOMAIN_ID=acf.DOMAIN_ID) "DOMAIN_ID",
(
    SELECT LISTAGG(name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
    FROM ACR_VIRTUAL_QUEUE
    WHERE FLOW_ID=acf.id
    GROUP BY FLOW_ID
) "VIRTUAL_QUEUE",
            (select outerHeight.name ofchrset
                from 
                acr_call_flow false,
                acr_cf_hs hs,
                acr_holiday_set s,
                acr_office_day od,
                acr_office_day_set Os, 
                acr_office_hour_set oh
        WHERE
        od.flow_id = f.id and 
        hs.flow_id(+) =f.id and 
        hs.hs_id= s.id(+) and
        oh.id=os.ohs.id and 
        os.od_id=od.id and 
        f.id=acf.id        
                ) "OFFICE_HOUR_SET"
                from ACR_CALL_FLOW acf)`;

let whereConstant = "";
let whereString = "";
let hasMoreThanOneCondition = false;
let parameterizedQueryObjects = [];
req.body.searchFields.forEach((field) => {
  whereConstant = " WHERE ";
  if (hasMoreThanOneCondition) {
    whereString += req.body.checkAll ? "AND" : "OR";
  }
  let checkfield = field.value.toUpperCase();
  if (checkfield == "DEBUG") {
    field.VALUE = "3";
  }
  if (checkfield == "ERROR") {
    field.VALUE = "2";
  }
  if (checkfield == "INFO") {
    field.VALUE = "1";
  }
  if (checkfield == "WARN") {
    field.VALUE = "0";
  }

  whereString += `UPPER(${field.field})`;
  switch (field.operator) {
    case "EQUALS":
    case "CONTAINS":
      whereString += `LIKE '%' || UPPER(:${field.field}) || '%'`;
      break;
    case "DOESNT_EQUALS":
    case "DOESNT_CONTAIN":
      whereString += `NOT LIKE  UPPER(:${field.field}) || '%'`;
      break;
    case "STARTS_WITH":
      whereString += ` LIKE  UPPER(:${field.field}) || '%'`;
      break;
  }
  parameterizedQueryObjects.push(field.value.replace(/\*/g, "%"));
  hasMoreThanOneCondition = true;
});

let results = await Connection.execute(
  query + (whereString !== "" ? whereConstant + whereString : ""),
  parameterizedQueryObjects,
  { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT }
).catch((err) => {
  throw err;
});
```

Normal SQL query:

```
let sqlcheckGroupName = `select COUNT(*) FROM ACR_GROUP WHERE UPPER(NAME) = UPPER(${group})`;
let checkGroupName = await connection.execute(sqlCheckGroupName, {})
```

Converted to parameterized query:

```
let sqlcheckGroupName = `select COUNT(*) FROM ACR_GROUP WHERE UPPER(NAME) = UPPER(:group)`;
let checkGroupName = await connection.execute(sqlCheckGroupName, {group: group});
```

In above mentioned, I have given an example saying how to change normal query to parameterized query. Similarly, I want to know  how to change the query which is having switch case statement to parameterized query?

I'm new to SQL and I'm not very good at writing queries.

Comment: You don't indicate how you're executing your SQL, or what runtime you're using. Please provide a minimal viable example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not trying to answer the parameterise question, but using this opportunity to point at some issues in your current query:

This sub-query refers to `outerHeight.name` but that table isn't mentioned anywhere else, so it should fail:

```
    , ( 
        SELECT outerHeight.name ofchrset
        FROM acr_call_flow false
            , acr_cf_hs hs
            , acr_holiday_set s
            , acr_office_day od
            , acr_office_day_set Os
            , acr_office_hour_set oh
        WHERE od.flow_id = f.id
            AND hs.flow_id(+) = f.id
            AND hs.hs_id = s.id(+)
            AND oh.id = os.ohs.id
            AND os.od_id = od.id
            AND f.id = acf.id
        ) "OFFICE_HOUR_SET"
```

AND that sub-query is using ancient join syntax `(+)` that really should never be used any longer.

More broadly you are using many "correlated sub-queries" and these are notorious for poor (slow) performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT acf.ID "call_flow_ID"
        , acf.Name "CALL_FLOW_NAME"
        , acf.SLO "SERVICE_OBJECTIVE"
        , acf.LOG_FILTER "LOG_FILTER"
        , acf.Max_jump
        
        , ( /* this would be more efficient as a joined subquery */
            SELECT LISTAGG(NAME, ',') WITHIN
            GROUP (
                    ORDER BY name
                    )
            FROM ACR_SUBROUTINE acs
            RIGHT JOIN ACR_CALL_FLOW_SUB ON SUB_ID = acs.ID
            WHERE FLOW_ID = acf.ID
                AND TYPE IN ('ANC')
            GROUP BY TYPE
            ) "ANNOUNCEMENT_TREATMENT"
            
        , ( /* this runs the risk of returning more than 1 row which would produce an eror */
            /* you may be able to left join this table to get the same outcome */
            SELECT NAME
            FROM ACR_USER_DOMAIN aud
            WHERE aud.DOMAIN_ID = acf.DOMAIN_ID
            ) "DOMAIN_NAME"
            
        , ( /* this runs the risk of returning more than 1 row which would produce an eror */
            /* you may be able to left join this table to get the same outcome */
            SELECT DOMAIN_ID
            FROM ACR_USER_DOMAIN aud
            WHERE aud.DOMAIN_ID = acf.DOMAIN_ID
            ) "DOMAIN_ID"
            
        , ( /* this would be more efficient as a joined subquery */
            SELECT LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN
            GROUP (
                    ORDER BY name
                    )
            FROM ACR_VIRTUAL_QUEUE
            WHERE FLOW_ID = acf.id
            GROUP BY FLOW_ID
            ) "VIRTUAL_QUEUE"
            
        , ( /* unless you run an ancient version of Oracle STOP using ANTIQUE (+) syntax */
            SELECT outerHeight.name ofchrset
            FROM acr_call_flow false
                , acr_cf_hs hs
                , acr_holiday_set s
                , acr_office_day od
                , acr_office_day_set Os
                , acr_office_hour_set oh
            WHERE od.flow_id = f.id
                AND hs.flow_id(+) = f.id
                AND hs.hs_id = s.id(+)
                AND oh.id = os.ohs.id
                AND os.od_id = od.id
                AND f.id = acf.id
            ) "OFFICE_HOUR_SET"
            
    FROM ACR_CALL_FLOW acf
    )
```

I suggest this re-write (but of course is untested)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT acf.ID "call_flow_ID"
        , acf.Name "CALL_FLOW_NAME"
        , acf.SLO "SERVICE_OBJECTIVE"
        , acf.LOG_FILTER "LOG_FILTER"
        , acf.Max_jump

        , acs.ANNOUNCEMENT_TREATMENT
        , aud.NAME "DOMAIN_NAME"    
        , aud.DOMAIN_ID
        , avq.VIRTUAL_QUEUE
        
        /* ancient syntax sub-query removed as it is incomplete, see under for more */
        --, aod.OFFICE_HOUR_SET
            
    FROM ACR_CALL_FLOW acf
    LEFT JOIN ACR_USER_DOMAIN aud ON aud.DOMAIN_ID = acf.DOMAIN_ID
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT FLOW_ID, LISTAGG(NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY name ) "ANNOUNCEMENT_TREATMENT"
            FROM ACR_SUBROUTINE acs
            RIGHT JOIN ACR_CALL_FLOW_SUB ON SUB_ID = acs.ID /* is right join really neccessary */
            WHERE TYPE IN ('ANC')
            GROUP BY FLOW_ID
            ) acs ON acs.FLOW_ID = acf.ID
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT FLOW_ID, LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY name ) "VIRTUAL_QUEUE"
            FROM ACR_VIRTUAL_QUEUE 
            GROUP BY FLOW_ID
            ) avq ON FLOW_ID = acf.id
    )
```

Replacing the "correlated subqueries" with left joins allows for NULLs to be returned (which is equivalent to how the original subquery would behave). BUT, if there is more than 1 row matched in the joins then you will get more rows than before (*but avoid the error that the original sub-query would cause if more than 1 row is returned*).

The last sub-query appears to be wrong or incomplete  this is the best I can do with removing the ancient syntax:

```
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT f.id, outerHeight.name "OFFICE_HOUR_SET"
        FROM acr_call_flow f
        INNER JOIN acr_office_day od ON od.flow_id = f.id
        INNER JOIN acr_office_day_set os ON os.od_id = od.id
        INNER JOIN acr_office_hour_set oh ON oh.id = os.ohs.id
        LEFT JOIN acr_cf_hs hs ON hs.flow_id = f.id
        LEFT JOIN acr_holiday_set s ON s.id = hs.hs_id
        ) aod ON aod.id = acf.id
```

Note, there is a very good chance you do not need all those tables (especially the left joins) but you have to resolve the `outerHeight` issue - is it the alias `oh` perhaps?